# How do I get the value of integer Google Chart Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In my Tickets Model I have category_id which is a foreign key from the category table. I want to show on a PieChart on how many categories that has been used in the Tickets.

In my code I have this:

```
$data = array_map(
function($i) {
    return [$i['category_id']];},

Tickets::find()->select(['category_id'])->all()
);


echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
    'data' => array_merge([['Category id']], $data)
  )
);
```

My problem is that it doesn't show data at all, the PieChart does not display.
Right now in my tickets GridView I have:

- 5x Housekeeping Services
- 4x Engineering Services
- 1x Spa Services

A piechart supposed to display this services. I'm stuck to this problem.

Comment: `array_merge([['Category id']], $data)` output?

Comment: What do you mean? It does not show any data at all

Comment: what is the output of `array_merge([['Category id']], $data)`? Print using `print_r(array_merge([['Category id']], $data)); exit;`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Category id ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) )